# Creating couchbase full replica

Tags: couchbase

I have an environment with couchbase server that contains a lot of information (buckets, documents, indexes...). I want to Copy all this information to another environment's couchbase server. Is there any way to achive that? Maybe saving something locally to my computer and then upload it?

Comment: What version of Couchbase are you using?

Answer (score 0):

[cbbackupmgr](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/backup-restore/cbbackupmgr-backup.html) is probably what you are looking for (depending on which version of Couchbase you're using). It backs up (and restores) bucket settings, view definitions, GSI definitions, FTS index definitions, and key-value data.

Comment: I am using 4.6.2-3905. So it's ok?

Comment: Yes, it's included in 4.6 - https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/backup-restore/cbbackupmgr-backup.html

Comment: I am getting this error: "Bucket <bucket-name> dosen't exist".
I thought the restore command suppose to create new buckets..

Comment: In 4.x this was done intentionally, see: https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-26916